# Free In-App Purchases (GooglePlay)

Tags: android, google-play

We are developing a free application on iOS and Android. 
There will be around 25 in-app purchase products available on it.
Our manager asked us to promote one in-app purchase product for free.

It seems possible to do this on iTunes Connect, but I did not find an available way to do this on Google Play Developer Console.

While searching I did not find any way to set the price free on a particular in-app purchase product. Also, setting the price default value to 0 is not a valid way for the Google Play Console. In that case it asked me to enter a minimum value of 0.50.

Is there any way to temporarily give an in-app purchase product on Google Play for free? Did I miss something?

Comment: You missed that the site you posted on is for help with software development issues, not for help with using Google's web interface for product marketing. Unless you're thinking there is some code you can write in your application to influence the Google Play store, you've come to the wrong place I'm afraid.

Comment: You also missed the fact that Google Play has a once free forever free policy (which would probably also apply to IAP - hence the popularity of game currency): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en

Comment: I am sorry about that if stackoverflow is not appropriate for this kind of question. Thanks Morrison to point this out, I checked the link and I was not aware about the Google Play once free forever free policy.